# How to Properly Slice Icon Sheets in Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Beginner Question Here...

The question:  How to display a single icon from a 'png sheet' at a specific location and a specific size?

Background:  I recently found myself trying to write an educational game using javascript.  This question is how to deal with icon sheets.   The concept is a categorization game where a keyword drops onto the screen, and the user must determine what category the keyword goes in, where there are 7 categories.  The user presses a numeric key (1-7).  If correct, some flashy graphics and the keyword moves into the proper category, and points are awarded.  If incorrect, no points are awarded, then some other graphic transition and the

These categories are numbered and, rather than just typing the text in numbers, I decided a number icon would look better (1-7).  I found a png sheet of icon numbers in my search for number icons with (0-9)arranged in a matrix format.  These icons are arranged as follows in a single png file.

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

In the end, I want to display numbers 1-7 in specific locations and a much smaller scaled size.  I can display the entire sheet but don't know how to slice it properly.

One approach is to use Adobe photoshop and chop this sheet into individual icons.  For example, one.png contains just the icon number '1'; two.png contains just the number '2'.  While that may work, I expect there is a much more elegant solution.  Hence this question.   How do people usually use these icon sheets in javascript?

Game Engine:  I am using the phaser.io library and have successfully gotten through the tutorials.

Any advice is helpful...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a css question:
The way I would solve this problem is with [css sprite](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) with the `background-position` Properties.

```css
.image1, .image2, .image3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image: url('/images.png'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.image1 {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.image2 {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
}

.image3 {
  background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```